# What can be substituted in this system of equations with absolute values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, absolute-value

I am trying to figure out what I can substitute in this system of equations that involve absolute values -
$$|x+1|+|y|=1$$
$$|x+y|=2$$
My method is to do every combination and check with my cases to see what answers are correct. But they used a substitution method, it looks like they substituted $x$, but why do that in the first place? 

If anyone can point me as to what I could use as a substitute I would be grateful. The answers they got are this $(t,-2-t)$ and $t∈[-2,-1]$ and checking my answers I got the correct ones $(-2,0)$ and $(-1,-1)$ my only two answers from 8, but I would like to learn what they did too.

Comment: The second inequality is equivalent to $x+y = 2$ or $x+y = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x+y|=2 \implies (x+y=2)$ or $(x+y=-2)$. In the first case:
$$|x+1|+|y|=1 \implies |x+1|+|2-x|=1$$
Check the cases: If both are positive, we may remove the absolute value signs. If either is not positive, we must multiply the inside by negative one....

Otherwise:
$$|x+1|+|y|=1 \implies |x+1|+|-2-x|=1$$
And do the same here.

Comment: Is it allowed to express one variable inside a system of equations without doing the systems together?

Comment: @TheSlavSQuat what do you mean? The absolute value function is not injective and thus allows for multiple possibilities, all of which you must check.

Comment: You expressed $y$ in the first equation with what you got $y$ to be equal in your second. I am asking is that allowed?